# How to write a string and see if it is an expression?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, recursion, c++14

I am solving now an algorithmic problem using recursion. So what you need to find out in this problem is that if the string you inputed is an expression. So for example you have string "256+300-500" - this is an expression. So an expression is a string that contains numbers and the signes "+" and "-". The signs + and - cant stay one near eachother and also there cant be to + or 2 - near eachother. So "256++300" and "256+-600-500" is not an expression. Also if the number contains a letter in it then it is not an expression "54e2". So please help me make this program. I have done the part which sees if the number string is a number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int cif(char c)
{
if(isdigit(c))return 1;
else return 0;
}
int num (string s)
{
int z=s.length();
if(z==1) return cif(s[0]);
else
    {
      char c =s[0];
      s=s.substr(1);
      if(cif(c) && num(s))return 1; else return 0;
    }
}
int main()
{
 cout << num("2353Y3554");
 return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is 0 becase it is not a number, if it was the output would have been 1. Please help me make the program that I need continueing with this one, please.

Comment: *"there cant be to + or 2 - near eachother"* - I would say `"10--2"` is indeed a valid expression . . . otherwise you would exclude negative numbers from your program.

Comment: No, of course -- is equal to + but no, I need just different signs, please help someone

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem *cries* for a modern `regex` (and `string`) solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main(){

    std::regex expression{ "[\\d]+([-|+][\\d]+)+" };
    //Explanation:
    // [\\d]+  > at least one digit
    // ([-|+]  > - OR + character
    // [\\d]+  > at least one digit
    // )+      > at least once "- Or +" and "at least one digit" (grouping!)
    bool done = false;

    do {
        std::cout << "Type in an expression (\"+\" and/or \"-\" operator!): ";
        std::string str;
        std::cin >> str;

        if (std::regex_match(str, expression)){ //does match the rules!
            std::cout << "It's a valid expression!" << std::endl;
            done = true; //exit
        }
        else{ //it doesn't . . . type in again.
            std::cout << "That's not a valid expression . . . \n" << std::endl;
        }
    } while (!done);

    return 0;
}
```

Example run of the code:

```
Type in an expression ("+" and/or "-" operator!): Hello
That's not a valid expression . . .

Type in an expression ("+" and/or "-" operator!): 100+A
That's not a valid expression . . .

Type in an expression ("+" and/or "-" operator!): 100+
That's not a valid expression . . .

Type in an expression ("+" and/or "-" operator!): 100++42
That's not a valid expression . . .

Type in an expression ("+" and/or "-" operator!): +100+42
That's not a valid expression . . .

Type in an expression ("+" and/or "-" operator!): 100+42-50
It's a valid expression!
```

Answer (score 0):

**use loop with small check**

```
bool is_leeter(char str)
{
    char abc[27]= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    char ABC[27]= "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    for(int i=0;i<27;i++)
        if((abc[i] || ABC[i]) == str)
            return true;
    true false;
}

bool is_expression(char str)
{
    char exp[5]= "+-*/";
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        if(exp[i] == str)
            return true;
    true false;
}

for(int i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
{

    if(!is_leeter(str[i]) && !is_expression(str[i]) && !is_expression(str[i+1]))
    //do your thing
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but seems that none of this is using recursive , and also I would like very much to continue the problem with the code I have made please, thanks anyway it is very nice explained